# How to display the querying 'DB' for get-variable with multiple values?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am having a problem while displaying the value in the textbox.

I have check boxes that represent for applying job. When a user checks multiple check boxes and clicks the apply button, the `id` of the check box value is separated with `comma` and send to `applyView.php` file using ajax:

Example: `applyView.php?id=1,2,3`

and the script is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.job-apply').on('click', function(){
    var selected = $('input[name="job[]"]:checked').map(function(i,e){return e.id;}).get();
        var res = selected.join(",");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/applyView.php?id='+res,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.length > 0)
                {
                    var tmp = data[0];
                    $('#apply-title').attr('value',tmp.apply_title);
                }
               window.location.href = "apply.php";
        }
    });
});
```

And `applyView.php` file is:

```
require "dbconnect.php";
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `job_title` FROM `job` WHERE `job_id` IN ($id)");

$results = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
   $results[] = array(
      'apply_title' => $row['job_title'],
   );
}

$json = json_encode($results);

echo $json;
```

Output for the JSON Value is:

```
[{"apply_title":"Web developer"},{"apply_title":"Software Engineer"},{"apply_title":"Web developer"}]
```

And `apply.php` file is:

```
<form role="form" class="post-resume-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="job_title">Job Title</label>
        <input type="Text" class="form-control input" id="apply-title" value="" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Now the problem is to display only the value of the `id` `(#apply-title)` with separated by `comma` is it possible.

In the form text box it has to be like this:

```
"Web Developer","Software Engineer","Web Developer"
```

Help me out guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you want to take only the apply title, separated by commas.
Instead of the echo(or beneath it) you can add this code:

```
$allTitles = "";
foreach($results as $applytitle){
   $allTitles = $allTitles . $applytitle["apply_title"] . ",";
}
echo $allTitles;
```

This should output `Web Developer,Software Engineer,Web Developer,`.
The last comma(in the output) can be removed with a substring method.

NOTE: I haven't tested this, so it may not work! If you get an error, contact me

Comment: After the `echo $json;` or even replace it.

Comment: If I add or replace after `echo $json;` it shows an error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: Sorry, replace `$json` with `$results` in the foreach